Move gsap morphSVG to animejs
I have this animation on GSAP with morphSVG: https://codepen.io/asssc/pen/VwopGqL
document.querySelector('.buttons_start').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Green - Online
  gsap.to(".test.is-online path", { duration: 1, overwrite: true, morphSVG: "M.5,5.5C3.36,5.5,2.41,1,6.21,1s3.8,9,5.71,9,0-4.5,4.76-4.5S21.43,1,24.29,1s1.9,4.5,4.76,4.5" });
  
  // Red - Online
  gsap.to(".test.is-offline path", { duration: 1, overwrite: true, morphSVG: "M.5,5.5c2.85,0,1.9,3.16,5.71,3.16S10.01,1.88,14.77,1.88s4.4,6.64,8.76,6.77c2.85,0,2.65-3.16,5.51-3.16" });
})

document.querySelector('.buttons_stop').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Geen - Offline
  gsap.to(".test.is-online path", { duration: 0.5, overwrite: true, morphSVG: "M.5,5.5H29.04" });

  // Red - Offline
  gsap.to(".test.is-offline path", { duration: 0.5, overwrite: true, morphSVG: "M.5,5.5H29.04" });
})

I need to use Anime.js, but I can't start it smoothly, how do I make this animation exactly the same as on GSAP?
Anime.js example: https://codepen.io/asssc/pen/ExqWpbv
  const onlinePath = "M.5,5.5C3.36,5.5,2.41,1,6.21,1s3.8,9,5.71,9,0-4.5,4.76-4.5S21.43,1,24.29,1s1.9,4.5,4.76,4.5";
  const offlinePath = "M.5,5.5H29.04";
  const offlinePathRed = "M.5,5.5c2.85,0,1.9,3.16,5.71,3.16S10.01,1.88,14.77,1.88s4.4,6.64,8.76,6.77c2.85,0,2.65-3.16,5.51-3.16";

  document.querySelector('.buttons_start').addEventListener('click', () => {
    anime({
      targets: '.test.is-online path',
      d: [{ value: onlinePath }],
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    });

    anime({
      targets: '.test.is-offline path',
      d: [{ value: offlinePathRed }],
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    });
  });

  document.querySelector('.buttons_stop').addEventListener('click', () => {
    anime({
      targets: '.test.is-online path',
      d: [{ value: offlinePath }],
      duration: 500,
      easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    });

    anime({
      targets: '.test.is-offline path',
      d: [{ value: offlinePath }],
      duration: 500,
      easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    });
  });

